# Ending threading via tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

The code is like,

```
def start():
    def script(object):
        global stop
        stop = False
        while not stop:
            lbl['text'] = object.compare()

    p1 = th.Thread(target=script, args=[kansai], daemon=True)
    p1.start()

def stop():
    global stop
    stop = True


def on_closing():
    global stop
    stop = True
    root.quit()

root = tk.Tk()

start_btn = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start)
start_btn.grid(column=1, row=3)
quit_btn = tk.Button(root, text='Quit', command=stop)
quit_btn.grid(column=3, row=3)

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
root.mainloop()
```

My problem is that, when I clicked to close GUI, as defined in `on_closing`. the interface quit well but the script process became no-responding. When I hit the `quit` button, it went well, the script stoped until the current threading is finished. The script is based on selenium, taking about 20secs to finish.

Is there a way that when I click the exit button the code can wait until the threading is finished and then quit? Thanks.

Comment: Avoid using same name `stop` for both variable and function.  Also it is not recommended to update tkinter widget inside another thread as tkinter is not thread safe.  I have tested your code several times and cannot reproduce the *no-responding* issue.

Comment: @acw1668 The script part takes about 20secs to run, I think it's the part that caused the issue. If I close the interface, there's no reminder like `Process finished with exit code -1` in my IDE. And I can't start it again, the process just went no-responding and I need to restart the IDE again to run the code.

Comment: You need to provide sample code on `kansai.compare()` in order to reproduce the issue.  As you have used `daemon=True` on the thread, it is expected that the thread should be terminated when the main application is terminated.